# JavaFX theme switch button

Tags: button, javafx, model-view-controller, switch-statement, themes

I am currently creating the game PacMan using JavaFX MVC. I made an FXML file using SceneBuilder.

I have also added 2 themes: a classic theme and an X-Mas theme. The thing I want to do now is switch themes using a button which is created in the FXML file (see image: buttons 'classic' & 'xmas'.

Please help me out.

This is how it looks like:
[image: ThemePage]

This is my current code:
FXMLSideMenucontroller.fxml

```js
package sidemenu;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class FXMLSideMenuController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane ap_main;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane ap_gamefield;

    @FXML
    private Pane pnl_highscore;

    @FXML
    private Pane pnl_main;

    @FXML
    private Pane pnl_moeilijkheid;

    @FXML
    private VBox vbox_moeilijkheid;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btn_easy;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btn_medium;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btn_hard;

    @FXML
    private Pane pnl_credits;

    @FXML
    private Pane pnl_spelers;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btn_mraerts;

    @FXML
    private ImageView iview_mraerts;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btn_mrlemmens;

    @FXML
    private ImageView iview_mrlemmens;

    @FXML
    private Pane pnl_thema;

    @FXML
    private VBox vbox_thema;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btn_classic;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btn_xmas;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane ap_sidemenu;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane ap_sidepane;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btn_spelers;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btn_moeilijkheid;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btn_thema;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btn_highscore;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btn_credits;

    @FXML
    private FontAwesomeIconView iview_spelers;

    @FXML
    private FontAwesomeIconView iview_niveau;

    @FXML
    private FontAwesomeIconView iview_thema;

    @FXML
    private FontAwesomeIconView iview_highscore;

    @FXML
    private FontAwesomeIconView iview_credits;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource() == btn_spelers) {
            pnl_spelers.toFront();
        } else
        if(event.getSource() == btn_moeilijkheid) {
            pnl_moeilijkheid.toFront();
        } else
        if(event.getSource() == btn_thema) {
            pnl_thema.toFront();
        } else 
        if(event.getSource() == btn_highscore) {
            pnl_highscore.toFront();
        } else 
        if(event.getSource() == btn_credits) {
            pnl_credits.toFront();
        }
    }
    /**
    @FXML
    private void handleThemeSwitcher(ActionEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource() == btn_classic) {
            scene.getStylesheets().remove(getClass().getResource("Resources/style.css").toExternalForm());
            scene.getStylesheets().remove(getClass().getResource("Resources/xmas.css").toExternalForm());
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Resources/style.css").toExternalForm());// Load voor custom stylesheet       
        }
        if(event.getSource() == btn_xmas) {
            scene.getStylesheets().remove(getClass().getResource("Resources/style.css").toExternalForm());
            scene.getStylesheets().remove(getClass().getResource("Resources/xmas.css").toExternalForm());
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Resources/xmas.css").toExternalForm());// Load voor custom stylesheet  
        } 
    }   */
    
   /** @FXML
    private void closeMenuItem(ActionEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource() == icon_close) {
            pnl_main.toFront();
        }
    }*/
      
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        pnl_main.toFront();
    }
}
```

SideMenu.java

```js
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package sidemenu;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
public class SideMenu extends Application {
        
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {  
        Font.loadFont(
        SideMenu.class.getResource("Resources/CrackMan.TTF").toExternalForm(), 
        10); // Load voor custom font
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLSideMenu.fxml"));
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        //scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Resources/style.css").toExternalForm());// Load voor custom stylesheet       
        
        stage.setTitle("PacMan");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Style.css

```css
/* Classic */
#ap_sidemenu {
    -fx-background-color: #1919A6;
}

#ap_sidepane {
    -fx-background-color: #a8a8a8;
}

#pnl_main {
    -fx-background-color: #FFFF00;
}

#pnl_spelers {
    -fx-background-color: #FFFF00;
}

#pnl_moeilijkheid {
    -fx-background-color: #FFFF00;
}

#pnl_thema {
    -fx-background-color: #FFFF00;
}

#pnl_highscore {
    -fx-background-color: #FFFF00;
}

#pnl_credits {
    -fx-background-color: #FFFF00;
}

.button {
    -fx-background-radius: 50; 
    -fx-font-family: CrackMan;
    -fx-font-size: 26;
}

.button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #1919A6;
    -fx-background-radius: 50; 
    -fx-font-family: CrackMan;
    -fx-font-size: 26;
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-radius: 50;
    -fx-border-width: 1;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.button:pressed {
    -fx-background-color: #1919A6;
    -fx-background-radius: 50; 
    -fx-font-family: CrackMan;
    -fx-font-size: 26;
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-radius: 50;
    -fx-border-width: 3;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-rotate: 2;
}

.button:focused {
    -fx-background-color: #1919A6;
    -fx-background-radius: 50; 
    -fx-font-family: CrackMan;
    -fx-font-size: 26;
    -fx-text-fill: darkgrey;
}
```

xmas.css

```css
/* X-Mas*/
#ap_sidemenu {
    -fx-background-color: #165B33;
}

#ap_sidepane {
    -fx-background-color: #BB2528;
}

#pnl_main {
    -fx-background-color: #F8B229;
}

#pnl_spelers {
    -fx-background-color: #F8B229;
}

#pnl_moeilijkheid {
    -fx-background-color: #F8B229;
}

#pnl_thema {
    -fx-background-color: #F8B229;
}

#pnl_highscore {
    -fx-background-color: #F8B229;
}

#pnl_credits {
    -fx-background-color: #F8B229;
}

.button {
    -fx-background-radius: 50; 
    -fx-font-family: CrackMan;
    -fx-font-size: 26;
}

.button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #EA4630;
    -fx-background-radius: 50; 
    -fx-font-family: CrackMan;
    -fx-font-size: 26;
    -fx-border-color: #146B3A;
    -fx-border-radius: 50;
    -fx-border-width: 1;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.button:pressed {
    -fx-background-color: #BB2528;
    -fx-background-radius: 50; 
    -fx-font-family: CrackMan;
    -fx-font-size: 26;
    -fx-border-color: #165B33;
    -fx-border-radius: 50;
    -fx-border-width: 3;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-rotate: 2;
}

.button:focused {
    -fx-background-color: #BB2528;
    -fx-background-radius: 50; 
    -fx-font-family: CrackMan;
    -fx-font-size: 26;
    -fx-text-fill: darkgrey;
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm

Comment: Already read that but still don't know how to..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this doing this:

First, create the urls for both themes:

```
private String urlTheme1 = getClass().getResource("css1.css").toExternalForm();
private String urlTheme2 = getClass().getResource("css2.css").toExternalForm();
```

And when click on the "Change Style" button, you can do something like this:

```
  changeStylebtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                 @Override
                 public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
//Remove from scene the theme1(asumming you added to your scene when your app starts)
                     scene.getStylesheets().remove(urlTheme1); 

                     //Add the new theme
                     scene.getStylesheets().add(urlTheme2); 
                 }
            }
```

this will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! So I add all these lines to my controller?

Comment: @RingtoneFusion yes, if you have a method triggered when you click in the 'change style' button you can just do 'remove' and 'add' lines there.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I added all the lines you sent me into the Controller but it still doesn't change the themes.

Comment: @RingtoneFusion Please edit your question with the updated code to help you.

Comment: @RingtoneFusion You just need to have a reference to the Scene or Pane in your controller and call (scene or 'root' variable in your Main app) to do the add or remove of the styles. In your present controller you don't have a Scene variable in your controller.